# Odd behavior when trying to match hyphens with grep 2.27

Tags: grep, regular-expression

I have the following string:

```
-----BEGIN 1_1 CERTIFICATE-----
```

The following sequence does not match the hyphens:

```
grep -- "[A-Z\-\_]" file
```

When I remove `\_` the hyphens are matched:

```
grep -- "[A-Z\-]" file
```

If I remove the backslash I get `grep: Invalid range end`. Also it doesn't matter if I use `-E/egrep` or not - I get the same result.

What is the reason for that behavior?

Comment: Can you explain why you are using that pattern?  Do you understand what it is searching for?  Are you only trying to match hyphens? If so you need simply use: `grep '-'`.

Comment: I got it from a PHP framework - it's checking the chars in the variables of a HTTP request and if they match, it's letting the request pass. I modified it a little here of course.

Comment: It will actually match any uppercase character and any underscore character.  The brackets tell it to match any one of the characters inside.

Comment: Yes, I understand, but I why is `"[A-Z\-\_]"` not matching hyphens?

Comment: Not sure but if you put it at the end it will:  `grep '[A-Z_-]'`

Comment: Yes, I realized that already, take a look at my question once again :) That's what I want to know: Why is it matching the hyphen only if you put `\-` at the end. And why `[A-Z\-\_]` is not working.

Comment: I understand your question, that's why I commented my _workaround_ instead of posting it as an _answer_.  Also the escape characters are unnecessary.

Comment: I appreciate your help and I was not intended to be impolite. Sorry if it sounded like that :) Removing the escape chars, leads to `grep: Invalid range end` on my system.

Comment: It will do that when the hyphen is in the middle because it thinks you're trying to create a range.  (For example `A-Z` is a range specifying any uppercase letter between a and z).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When matching hyphens with a `[...]`, the hyphen needs to be first or last within it:

```
grep '[A-Z_-]' ...
```

If you put the hyphen anywhere else, it will be taken as specifying a range.

Also, `\` is literal in `[...]` (if the expression as a whole is quoted in the shell), so `[\-]` matches a backslash or a hyphen, and `[\-_]` probably matches a `\`, `]`, `^` or `_` (these are the characters in the range from `\` to `_` in the ASCII table).