# Does order in sed's regex character classes (e.g. [abc]) matter?

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I guess it's best to start with an example:

```
> echo "[20-20:10]Something" | sed -r -e 's/^\[[0-9\:\-]+(.*)$/\1/' 
]Something
> echo "[20-20:10]Something" | sed -r -e 's/^\[[0-9\-\:]+(.*)$/\1/' 
-20:10]Something
```

The only difference is that I swapped `:` and `-` characters in character class of regex. So: does the order of characters matter in sed's regex's character classes? I doesn't seem to matter on different regex systems, like https://regex101.com/.

I cannot find anything about this behaviour on Google, but I would like to know more, because I want to be sure to know what my scripts do.

Comment: No, it doesn't matter.

Comment: It matters *when the character is a hyphen* - see related [Odd behavior when trying to match hyphens with grep 2.27](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/443042/odd-behavior-when-trying-to-match-hyphens-with-grep-2-27) for example

Comment: It also matters when it's a `]` or `^` or if it's part of a character class name, e.g. `[:space:]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it matter, as `[0-9\:\-]` matches any single character from the set of digits, backslash, colon, or dash, while `[0-9\-\:]` does not match a dash.  In the second expression, the dash signifies a range between the backslash character and the backslash character (backslashes are literal is character classes), and the expression is equivalent to `[0-9\:]` (or, for that matter `[\0-9:]`).

The dash does *not* signify a range of characters if it's first (possibly after `^`) or last in a character class.

Also note that `sed` deals with POSIX regular expressions, which I don't think the site that you link to explicitly supports (see [Why does my regular expression work in X but not in Y?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119905)).

Comment: I see, thanks a lot. That means my problem/error was trying to escape the colon and dash which is allowed for some reason in https://regex101.com .

Answer (score 3):

There are a few rules. The important one in this case is that `-` is a range operation so you can say `a-f` rather than `abcdef` inside a class. To include a `-` as a literal character it is simplest if it is the last character in the class, but it can be the first or either end of a range.

If you want to negate a set of characters then the first character must be `^`. To include it as a literal then it mustn't be the first.

As `]` ends a class there is a special case that allows it to be the first (or second if the first character is `^` to negate the class), so `[]abc]` is a set of 4 characters, `a` `b` `c` or `]`.